# ASTM Protocol over Ethernet

Tags: c#

I am integrating Vitros 4600 using ASTM protocol on Ethernet, I have integrated another machine in past using ASTM over serial port which works fine.

1. Currently Issue I am facing is that Vitros Machine keep giving error `"Unexpected reply from LIS".`
2. My packet is as per document

> 1H|\^&|||HOST||||||||E1394-97
>
> ```
> 2P|1|00001|||FIRST^LAST^E||19780407|F||843TALLOAKSDR^HAILVILLEMD45831|||^^|||||||||||||||||||||
>
> 3O|1|CCY1311181^^||^^^1.0000+300+1.0|R||||||A||||5||||||||||O|||||
>
> 4L|1|N
> ```

I am implementing it in C# & can successfully read message from Vitros 4600 but Vitros 4600 cannot understand my reply.

In serial communication I notice there is ENQ/ACK like packets first then actuall message, will this occur in tcp too? as data come & send over tcp in stream not in packet.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference regarding the exchanged data. I have implemented ASTM protocols from analyzers that support both TCP and Serial communication. In any case ENQ - ACK are necessary in order to initialize a new communication cycle.